# Command line program to copy unique files?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer

Is there a command line program that can copy files which exist in one folder but do not exist in another **whilst taking into account that**:

1. The file in the destination folder may have been renamed and I don't want duplicates
2. Files are added to the source folder at any time and have random created, modified and accessed time-stamps

I have tried using robocopy, but there are two issues:

- `robocopy /mir` will copy files, but if a file in the destination folder has been renamed (point #1) then the original filename will be copied again the next time it is run.
- `robocopy /maxage:1` will copy files in the last day, but since files added have random timestamps (point #2) then many files newly added files won't be copied as they are older than that.

Is there something else out there that can do what I want?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for software, which is off topic, but I am not sure that is what you are asking. Can you clarify what you mean by "tool"? Are you simply asking for help with using the command line to do this? Or are you looking for software that does this?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a program which can do such a thing. I'll try and tidy up the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified this condition:

> The file in the destination folder may have been renamed and I don't want duplicates

This condition literally eliminates all candidates I know on both Windows and Linux. It eliminates the file name from the equation requiring the copying app to compare files based on their size and contents only. (Your second condition takes the time stamp out of the equation as well.)

**What you should do** is to roll up your sleeves and start writing a PowerShell script that creates SHA-1 hashes from all files (both in the source and destination), compares the hashes in the source and destination, and finally transfer files that have unique hashes.

Comment: Shame, I'm not averse to rolling up my sleeves - but I was really hoping that someone else had already done something!